# angularjs compare bound value after navigation

Tags: angularjs, integration-testing, karma-runner

I encounter a problem that I can't resolve with the angularjs online help.

I'm writing angularjs/karma scenario test where I want to verify that a part a view which displays a purse amount persists after page navigation. The purse amount comes from a bound value.

View code:

```
<div class="label">Mon Compte<br>{{ User.getBalance() | currency }}</div>
```

Scenario code:

```
var b1 = binding('User.getBalance() | currency');
browser().navigateTo('/another-route');
var b2 = binding('User.getBalance() | currency');
expect(b1).toEqual(b2);
```

Failed scenario result:

```
expected {"name":"select binding 'User.getBalance() | currency'","fulfilled":true,"value":"4 353,90 €"} but was "4 353,90 €"
```

What I understand is that it tries to compare a promise with text value which doesn't work, but I have no idea to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you are actually trying to test. Are you trying to assert that the text displayed in your VIEW is some value or are you trying to assert that the MODEL is staying the same? If it's the VIEW you are interested in you are on the right track. My suggestion would be to use [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) rather than Karma.

Take a look at the documentation and let me know if you still can't get your tests working.

On the other hand if it is the MODEL you are interested in, things become a bit more complicated. You will not be able to simulate the browser navigation with a standard unit test. You would have to either create a mock service that lets you simulate the route provider or use a third party library like ngMidwayTester. Take a look [here](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-karma.html#testing-routes) for more help with that.